# browser back button form fields empty

Tags: php, session

I have session_start in all my code and this is working. When I click the browser back button and when i include this in my header.php file:

```
header_remove("Expires");
header_remove("Cache-Control");
header_remove("Pragma");
header_remove("Last-Modified")
```

the session variable `$_SESSION['IAMAVARIABLE']` DOES NOT print/echo on the screen. But my form fields value appears.
when i comment this out:

```
/*
header_remove("Expires");
header_remove("Cache-Control");
header_remove("Pragma");
header_remove("Last-Modified")
*/
```

the session variable `$_SESSION['IAMAVARIABLE']` print/echo and my form fields value disappear.

I want both of them at to show at all times when i click the browser back button.
any ideas what i am doing wrong.
many thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

From Php.net

[header_remove](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php)

> **Caution**
>
> This function will remove all headers set by PHP, including cookies,
>   session and the X-Powered-By headers.

Missing a semicolon

```
header_remove("Last-Modified")
                              ^
```

It must be

```
header_remove("Last-Modified");
```